# How to make people fear death, if they know that there's a (benevolent) afterlife?

Tags: society, religion, death

A problem with many fantasy fictions that I have, such as Elder Scrolls and LotR, is that people know that there's an afterlife, a good one at that, so why fear death? Why mourn those who died? As long as you're faithful/good, you're going to heaven/paradise/nirvana/etc...

How would it be possible to, even in such terms, make one fear death?

Edit - Thanks everyone for answering, this has been more than educational considering the vast amount of answers with different philosophies, but I'm afraid I can't go into more detail on this question, because I'm not currently making much use of this in a fiction, though I plan on in the near future, and I'm trying to grasp a basic understanding on how a society would fear death if it was empirically proven that there is a benevolent afterlife.

Comment: Same way as with any religion that promises afterlife - no one can be absolutely sure that he goes to heaven rather than hell.

Comment: There are many religions who promise some form of afterlife. Every follower probably has their own reasons to fear death, or perhaps they do not. History is filled with individuals who became martyrs for causes they believed in. This sounds like an incredibly personal subject that is entirely dependent upon the individual in question.

Comment: Are you referring to the case where an individual *knows* that there is an afterlife (i.e. literally has no doubt, and can't imagine doubting it), and *knows* that they've been faithful good (i.e. Has the doucmentation ready to show to St Paul as he reachest the gates), how to make that individual fear?  Most religious systems don't have to worry about that, because such certainty is unheard of.  However, it is part of the process for convincing a religious zealot to go to war.. that sort of confidence is known to make people fearless, for better or for worse.

Comment: I don't know why you're being down voted. This seems like a good question to me. As for mourning death, one explanation is that the living person will not get to see the dead person for quite a while, and depending on the nature of the afterlife, they might never see them again. Fearing death might be similar, since you will be separated from the ones you love. Also, some religions count suicide as a sin to prevent believers from just getting to the afterlife right then and there. Also, make sure to note the difference between the reader knowing there's an afterlife, and the character knowing.

Comment: Fear of death is a biological response that is outside the logical reasoning process. I would make this an answer, but that's literally all I have to say.

Comment: Quick question: Would they not fear weakness, They know there is an afterlife waiting for them IF they make all the right decisions, think all the right thoughts, and feel all the right feelings. But if a single stray thought can put that in doubt would they be afraid? If constant perfect spelling is nessesary I would be afraid.

Comment: Which are you looking for: fear of death, or mourning the loss of others?  They're really very different concepts, psychologically.

Comment: People are sad when their friend moves away. Even if there is a really good after life, you'd be sad if you had to leave everything you had in this life.

Comment: @CortAmmon "Most religious systems don't have to worry about that, because such certainty is unheard of" I don't want to start an internet fight over religion, but [absolute knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assurance_(theology)) of salvation is important to several Protestant denominations. I can tell you that I know people who are more confidant in their assurance than they are that gravity will be working tomorrow. Such certainty is, in my view, common on Earth, but not common on internet forums.

Comment: @kingledion The main problem with this idea of complete certainty in something through faith, is these beliefs, so strongly held, aren't limited to a certain religion/denomination. No, rather they exist within followers of all religions, religions which contradict each other vehemently, religions that have as core theological constructs the ideas that every other religion is false while their own doctrine is infallible. As you can see, all religions claim to be the right one, but only one (at most) ultimately can be. So where does this leave the notion of assurance in your view?

Comment: @AngelPray It doesn't matter that they can't all be correct. What matters in the scope of this question is that people actually believe this.

Comment: @sphennings and all the other VTCers.  This is a fairly well scoped psychology question.  Why, exactly, was it put on hold?  It has a lot in common with, "people know there's a glass platform extending out over the Grand Canyon... so why do people fear walking on it?"  Recommending to reopen.

Comment: @JBH It's hard to make sense of your point when your example question isn't about building a fictional world. "Why are people afraid of walking on the [grand canyon skywalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Canyon_Skywalk)?" has nothing to do with building a fictional world. I don't see how that example supports your argument.

Comment: @sphennings, I agree with JBH. It is a fairly good psychology question. It is also on topic since it deals with fictional universes where the afterlife is proven to exist. The question could be reworded a bit, though. I am voting to reopen.

Comment: Compare it to going to the dentist: you're pretty sure that you're going to come out ok on the "other side", and your toothache will be gone, but still, most people do not find the actual visit at all pleasant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One could fear death if motivated to achieve goals in life.  The artist who was never appreciated in his time might fear death if he aspires to see the fruits of his labor change the world.  Many a fear of one's own death are driven not by the unknown but the lack of tangible legacy that they leave behind.  Death is inevitable, but men can live beyond death through their achievements and the memories of others, but then for how long before they fade?

Remember, Ozymandias, King of Kings, implored people who believed themselves mighty to look upon his works and achievements and compare his legacy to theirs, and despair at the thought of beating that.

Comment: Unfinished Business! That's a good answer +1.

Answer (score 5):

Even if you have *positive evidence* there's an afterlife (as opposed to *believing* there's one) there still are several (possible) reasons to try to avoid death as long as possible:

- There may be some kind of judgment on your whole life before Valhalla's doors will open; it's extremely unlikely someone can be really sure of the outcome.
- Your good judgment may depend on your deeds, and being killed too easily would look really bad on your slate (variation on the above).
- Family bonds may be strong and dying young means you won't support your family as you should.
- If you are a warrior being unafraid to die is a boon, up to a point (in medieval Japan they had the problem of keeping Samurai from uselessly throwing away their life).
- Dying you could have a nice "heavenly" life, but you surely lose some earthly things, such as having children.

Comment: exactly, life is a proving ground for the afterlife so if you expedite it you run the risk of not receiving a good judgment. THE REAL QUESTION should be ; if there were certain judgement based afterlife, would anyone commit evil?

Comment: @anon There is a certain judgment based _life_ and people still commit murders...

Comment: @anon: Definition of "good" and "evil" is not so unambiguous as some people likes to think.

Comment: @ZioByte I was agreeing with (first vote) however the point of my comment. If there is a clear after life and clear judgment, than good and evil is also clear. In that case the question becomes can "evil" really exist. Obviously there will always be a portion of society psychologically hard wired for "evil" but overall wouldn't its occurrence be dramatically reduced?

Comment: @anon: my point is there's no such a thing as "good" or "evil"; they are *opinions* based on our (forcefully imperfect) understanding of situation. Nobody, not even psychopaths, do "evil" for the sake of doing "evil"; *every* evil-doer (and do gooder, of course) *thinks* he is justified by specific circumstances to do what he's doing. In most cases he abides to do "evil" in order to "avoid a greater evil", or so he thinks while doing it. The important part in most religions is God(s) is(are) inhumanly fair and thus they *know* when and who deserves punishments. None on Earth can do the same.

Comment: @ZioByte I think you confuse my usage of terms "good and evil" to mean current perspectives of good and evil which I was not referring to. By having an explicity judgemental religious system you inherently define "good and evil". If you are Viking who rapes and murders his enemies and dies nobly in the heat of battle then you are technically "good" however if you are a coward in fear of following order and committing genocide then you are "bad" as described by your Viking faith.

Comment: @anon: I do understand you, and I concur... to a point. Problem is whenever you try to codify behavior in a (small) set of rules, as it's always the case with religions, you unavoidably over-simplify reality and thus inherently create loopholes where personal (however fallacious) judgement is required. Law says "do not kill", but David killed Goliath, Abram was requested to kill Isaak and countless other examples. Something similar holds true for every religion and for every Law. Coward Vikings refusing to exterminate doubtless felt perfectly justified to do so and bet Wotan would understand.

Comment: So now I get where you are going with religious codification however that is outside of our scope as it would be an element of this world. All that you can base the argument of errors due to codification is religions who do not have proven judgment/afterlife which aren't in the same category here.

Answer (score 2):

## It happens just like it does with humanity

> For God so loved the world that he gave his one and only Son, that
>   whoever believes in him shall not perish but have eternal life. - John 3:16

I am a Christian and I believe that is true. Though I am not so familiar with other religions, I am reasonably sure that the other Abrahamic religions (Judaism, [Islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/44952/is-there-a-textual-promise-of-eternal-life-in-the-quran), Mormonism) hold such scriptural promises in similarly high esteem. There are about a billion Christians around and a similar number of Muslims. So we can say with some confidence that there are billions of humans who *know* that there is a benevolent afterlife that they can reach.

As a digression, I would argue that the promise of said benevolent afterlife is the most important part motivating religion. Religion often doesn't offer that much on Earth; it forbids such enjoyable things as sex, wealth, booze and bacon; it requires such onerous sacrifices as tithing, turning the other cheek, and even martyrdom. So the promise is one that many people wrestle with: what happens when I die? For many people the promise of comfort and salvation from the yawning void of forever is what makes you religious. I can tell you from first person experience the difference between hearing about the afterlife and *knowing* about the afterlife.

Back to the main argument, if we accept that billions on Earth *do* believe in a benevolent afterlife, then those same people as a whole display fear of death and mourning for those loss. The reasons are many, but can include fear of the pain that often accompanies dying, prioritization of the present over a nebulous future (i.e. I want to see my dad today, not in heaven), and general uncertainty about the truth of the afterlife--lack of faith.

Faith and reason, fragile apart but strong together, are ever at war in the mind and soul of Man. The fruits of this struggle are fear and doubt, bubbling up from the sub-conscious, threatening to destroy both.

Comment: Faith ≠ knowledge. "general uncertainty about the truth of the afterlife" is what this question apparently removes. At least in examples shown, you can simply ask someone who been there.

Comment: @Mołot No offense to you, but you must understand that this is your _opinion_. Yes: belief in gravity and math and science and everything is your _opinion_. I know people as assured of salvation through Jesus as you are in $F=ma$. There are many people whose uncertainty about the afterlife is less than their uncertainty about arithmetic. What you think is knowledge is considered by others to be faith, and what you view as faith, they think of as knowledge.

Comment: You know people who are assured of salvation through Jesus, but there are more people on Earth who do _not_ hold that belief than who do. So what makes your position right as opposed to say, a Mormon or a Hindu or a Jew? There's clearly no objective way of proving the case, otherwise that would have been done long ago and the only people who disagreed would be easily dismissed cranks. Thus, faith. On the other hand, it's trivial to demonstrate gravity exists and math works, and they'll work the exact same way for a Christian and an atheist. No faith required because anyone can _prove_.

Comment: No, lack of knowledge about afterlife is not an opinion, it's a fact. Afterlife is (if at all) something no one here ever experienced, tested, proved etc... Faith is ok, but mistaking it for knowledge is what lead to religious wars.

Comment: @KeithMorrison You are using a you-centric point of view. Your 'trivial' proofs of math are as meaningless to some people as their proofs of God's existence. You are arguing that those people are wrong, but _from their point of view your argument has no evidence_. See what I'm getting at here? This has nothing to do with science, this is a simple application of logic: you reach different points of _knowledge_ when you start with different assumptions.

Comment: @Mołot You are trying to distinguish between faith and knowledge. I am simply stating (as a fact, that I know first hand) that other people have _different definitions of the concepts of faith and knowledge_. Heck, just look at politics and you can see that other people have clearly different definitions of _fact_.

Comment: "alternative facts" and "alternative knowledge" are just fancy names for lies.

Comment: @Mołot Can't you see that your opponents would use the exact same argument against you?

Comment: I don't agree with everything in this answer, but I'm surprised to see a delete vote. I'd be interested in hearing a rationale for that; I feel like it answers the question.

Comment: @kingledion, with the subjects of both gravity and math, I can demonstrate them. I can make predictions based on them, and those predictions can be shown to be objectively true or false. To use an obvious example, it was predicted long before you could physically test it that a feather and hammer will, if released at the same time standing on the moon, fall at the same rate and hit the ground at the same time. And then Dave Scott did it in 1971. There is no equivalent for belief in the afterlife. That is a matter of faith, and trying to equate the two does a disservice to faith _and_ science.

Comment: @kingledion To claim you "know" what happens after you die is simply and utterly the height of arrogance. To believe based on faith is one thing, but to claim you _know_ something without any evidence, is quite another. Beyond that the only thing I can think of adding is this: what compels you to have such high self-assurance and confidence in yourself?

Comment: @AngelPray First, calling me arrogant is an insult, not an argument. Second, why do you feel the need to convince me of this? What I am arguing is that _I think this way_. In the scope of this question, I am saying that I (and up to billions like me) am a first person example of people who _know_ there is a benevolent afterlife and yet fear death. That answers the question. My personal beliefs aren't really any of your business, are they? You ought to apologize for insulting me, I did no such thing to you.

Comment: @kingledion Saying you were arrogant was neither meant as an insult nor an argument (merely an observation). The issue is your use of the word "know", in the worlds OP gave as examples (Elder Scrolls and the LotR series) the people have overwhelming evidence that an afterlife exists, they can easily and consistently prove its existance. On the other hand people (such as yourself, as it would seem) who claim to know a benevolent afterlife exists do not and cannot. Thus, we cannot exclude for instance, the possibility that they still fear death as they aren't truely sure they're right. (1/2)

Comment: @kingledion Indeed perhaps they merely claim to believe they know with absolute certainty. Perhaps deep down they have doubts (I'd like to make it clear however that I am not accusing religious folk of the latter, only saying that we cannot rule it out). It has to be acknowledged that apparently diehard believers do rather frequently convert/renounce religion in general. Perhaps though they only claimed to have no doubts, either way we cannot say. All of this simply means that real people are not good case studies for the behaviours of people living in worlds like those mentioned by OP. (2/2)

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat similar to kingledion's answer.  As a Christian, I absolutely **know** that I will go to heaven when I die.  However, that doesn't mean I'm in a hurry to get there.  If I were to meet an untimely death, I'd be very concerned about the wife I leave behind - for many reasons that should be obvious.  If we had children, I'd be equally concerned about their welfare.  And though my employer could replace me eventually, it would certainly be disruptive.  In short, there are people on earth who depend on me, and I'm not willing to turn my back on them, even with the promise of something better for me.

Comment: Correction - You believe, you don't know. Knowing requires proof and there isn't a single religion out there with a shred of proof of any of their claims. Everything is taken on blind faith alone. (Hint: The Bible isn't proof)

Comment: We can argue back and forth on that point for the rest of our lives.  It's not relevant to the point I was making however.  Suffice it to say that I feel assured of my salvation.  Why, then, would I be afraid of death?  For the reasons outlined above - namely, the negative impact on those left behind.  I think that's a relevant answer to the question regardless of what *others* think about a person's religious doctrine.

Comment: Still comes back to the difference between knowing and believing. Unless you have proof, it's a belief. All you have is a book and it's full of mistakes. As for Christianity, God has a plan for everyone thus worrying about people left behind when you die isn't logical. It means you have no faith in God's plan.

Comment: The original question, which you keep choosing to ignore, asks why someone might fear death even if he feels his own soul (however you define that) is secure. I cited my own Christian faith for illustration purposes, but the original question is more broad. You have yet to cogently explain why you think concern for people left behind is not a legitimate reason to fear dying.  It seems to me that your comments are more motivated by anti-christian bigotry than a face-value assessment of my answer.

Comment: I just dislike people people claiming to know things despite actually having absolutely no knowledge on the matter whatsoever. You have a belief. Nothing more. Nothing less. I'm happy to be corrected should you actually have proof

Comment: @Thorne  Do you believe that black holes exist or any other scientific phenomenon is true?  Did you measure it yourself or are you taking the word of other scientists at face value?  If many scientists say that X is true and you believe them that is not proof - that is just blind faith in what they told you.  You need to do the experiments yourself to have proof.  In this regard the bible is just as much proof as any peer reviewed journal article.  I'm not saying scientific evidence of these things doesn't exist - I'm saying you believe it exists because you take the word of those who know.

Comment: Nobody knows if there is an afterlife. As for the Bible being equivalent to a peer reviewed article, it has a talking donkey in it so no I can't take it seriously unless they include Shrek and Fiona too.

Comment: @Thorne I think you're wrong but I'm not going to spend any more time arguing about it.  Rather, I'll just point out that I don't think it's reasonable to completely ignore the **substance** of my answer, but downvote anyway simply because my supporting argument offends your sensibilities.